# Error "bad value 'armv8+crc+simd+crypto' for '-march=' switch"

Tags: compiler-errors, cross-compiling

So i'm trying to cross-compile [Box64](https://github.com/ptitSeb/box64) using amd64 for aarch64 but it's giving me this error, i'm using Alpine Linux since i need it to compile with musl.

[Image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjzm3.png)

I know this error has to do with the compiler but i can't figure out what's wrong with it.

Comment: please do not post link or images of errors , you should post the error message